# Confusing reverse DNS IP replacement, ever since I edited /etc/hosts

Tags: macos, network, dns

A while ago I was trying to set up convenient ssh to a server, so I added an entry to `/etc/hosts` (not real IP):

```
# Host Database
104.111.11.1    dokku.1
```

I've realized since then that using `~/.ssh/config` is a better solution, so I removed the `hosts` entry. But ever since then, the IP seems to reverse-resolve to `dokku.1` when I try to visit that IP in safari, it replaces it with dokku.1, then fails to resolve the hostname. Does anyone know where that resolving behavior is coming from, and how to stop it? I have rebooted the computer since I removed the entry.

macOS 10.12.6

Comment: DNS resolution is not done in the SSH config file. Using the convention `dokku.1` is attempting to resolve a `.1` domain which doesn't exist anywhere.  You should be using `dokku-1` in either `hosts` or `known_hosts`

Answer (score 1):

Welp, turns out it's actually the server at the IP address returning an HTTP 301 redirect. It was just so fast I didn't notice.